# Using expression tree call a method with the same name on 2 unrelated classes

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees, linq-expressions

Suppose I have a base class like the following

```
public abstract class BaseHelloWorld<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    public abstract IEnumerable<T> DoSomething();
}
```

and another like

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public abstract void DoSomethingInPayload();
}
```

Then I have 4 classes like:

```
public class Payload1 : BaseEntity
{
    public override void DoSomethingInPayload()
    {
        Console.Write("Hello world");
    }
}

public class Class1 : BaseHelloWorld<Payload1>
{
    public override IEnumerable<Payload1> DoSomething()
    {
        return new List<Payload1> {  };
    }
}   

public class Payload2 : BaseEntity
{
    public override void DoSomethingInPayload()
    {
        Console.Write("Goodbye world");
    }
}

public class Class2 : BaseHelloWorld<Payload2>
{
    public override IEnumerable<Payload2> DoSomething()
    {
        return new List<Payload2>() { };
    }
}
```

Although I have shown code here, suppose these where third party libraries that I don't have code for and I want to extend them. What I want to do is to be able to create a single extension method that will allow me to call the DoSomethingInPayload() method on the payload class similar to

```
public static void CallDoSomething<T>(this BaseHelloWorld<T> theClass) where T: BaseEntity
{
    theClass.DoSomethingInPayload();
}
```

Obviously this will not work so I started looking at expression trees. My reading suggests this is possible to do with expression trees but I cant figure it out. After hours of trying and getting nowhere I am unsure if my theory is correct. Therefore could you please tell me:

A) Is it possible to do this with expression trees
 B) If so how would I do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about `IEnumerable<T> CallDoSomething<T>(this BaseHelloWorld<T> theClass)` ?

Comment: It's possible, but why expression trees (or reflection) - `dynamic` is just for that, e.g. `return ((dynamic)theClass).DoSomething();`

Comment: because you cant use dynamic as the first parameter in extension methods

Comment: @John I'm talking about the **implementation** of your `public static IEnumerable<T> CallDoSomething<T>(this T theClass)` extension method.

Comment: @Aleks Andreev: Yes you are correct in the example I gave that would work. I was trying to do a trivial example and didn't quite show the problem correctly. My apologies I will update with a more complete example which shows why this wouldn't work like in my real world scenario

Comment: @IvanStoev I have updated the question to give a better demonstration of the problem. I think this shows why I don't think the Dynamic would work please feel free to correct me if you believe me to be wrong

Comment: You can create overloads of your extension methods for each base class. The runtime will pick the right overload. It will feel as one single extension method.

Comment: @GertArnold Yes that's currently what I do but was wanting to make one method for all. Although this is a trivial solution I have a real world problem and that as lots of classes that would need methods creating for. As the method name is the same in each case I was hoping for one extension method

Answer (score 1):

Your own example is not working because `T` is a different type in the input and return parameters.

Indeed, as @AleksAdreev mentioned, you could simply try:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> CallDoSomething<T>(this BaseHelloWorld<T> theClass)
{
    return theClass.DoSomething();
}
```

Which can then be called as follows:

```
var someClass = new Class2();
var someResult = someClass.CallDoSomething();
```

Comment: I attempted to give a trivial demonstration in my example which could have been fixed by @AleksAdreev solution. My real world example is very complex and I don't have all the source code so that was my attempt to demonstrate. I have updated the question to show the problem that I am having

Comment: @John And why wouldn't it work? Just add the required constraint: `where T: BaseEntity`

Comment: Because in my haste to correct the question I made a mistake in the example. I'm really sorry about that I will correct it :(

Comment: @John what does your latest edit change? The solution is still valid, the fact that `BaseEntity` is an abstract class changes nothing.

Comment: The class that is passed in is of type of the base class which as no knowledge of the method DoSomethingInPayload() as this is in a more derived class. I happen to know this method will always exist so I want to make a call in it. The expression tree route seems to be able to give me that ability but I was unable to figure it out. If I'm misunderstanding you please could you show me a example because currently what I have shown will not compile due to it being nonsense.